# Ansible community.general.ssh_config: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storm'

Tags: python, ssh, pip, ansible

I'm doing this:

```yaml
- name: Add Bitbucket in the SSH configuration
  community.general.ssh_config:
    user: "{{ jenkins_user }}"
    host: bitbucket
    remote_user: git
    hostname: "{{ bitbucket_hostname }}"
    port: '7999'
    identity_file: "/home/{{ jenkins_user }}/.ssh/{{ ssh_private_key }}"
    state: present
```

I get this error:

```
amazon-ebs: TASK [Add Bitbucket in the SSH configuration] **********************************
amazon-ebs: Friday 16 April 2021  14:35:03 +0200 (0:00:00.599)       0:17:50.265 **********
amazon-ebs: An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storm'
amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (stormssh) on ip-172-31-4-198's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

I already did

```sh
pip install storm
```

When doing this before `community.general.ssh_config`:

```yaml
- name: Install storm python package
  pip:
    name: storm
```

I get this error:

> amazon-ebs: TASK [Install storm python package] ********************************************[0m[0;32m
> amazon-ebs: Friday 16 April 2021  15:17:06 +0200 (0:00:00.594)       0:18:14.936 **********[0m[0;32m
> amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/pip3", "install", "storm"], "msg": "stdout: Collecting storm\n  Downloading storm-0.24.tar.gz (281 kB)\nRequirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from storm) (1.14.0)\nBuilding wheels for collected packages: storm\n  Building wheel for storm (setup.py): started\n  Building wheel for storm (setup.py): finished with status 'error'\n  Running setup.py clean for storm\nFailed to build storm\nInstalling collected packages: storm\n    Running setup.py install for storm: started\n    Running setup.py install for storm: finished with status 'error'\n\n:stderr:   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:\n   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-isx3tjl6\n       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/\n  Complete output (124 lines):\n  running bdist_wheel\n  running build\n  running build_py\n  creating build\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/uri.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/database.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/properties.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/locals.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/references.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/xid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/store.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/sqlobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/event.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/variables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/expr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/tracer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n  copying storm/twisted/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n  copying storm/twisted/transact.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n  copying storm/twisted/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n  copying storm/databases/postgres.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n  copying storm/databases/sqlite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n  copying storm/databases/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/uri.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/database.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/properties.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/helper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/sqlobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/event.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/variables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/expr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/tracer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/mocker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  copying storm/tests/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/metaconfigure.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/metadirectives.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/adapters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/zstorm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/schema.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/conf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n  copying storm/schema/schema.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n  copying storm/schema/sharding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n  copying storm/schema/patch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n  copying storm/schema/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/twisted\n  copying storm/tests/twisted/transact.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/twisted\n  copying storm/tests/twisted/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/twisted\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n  copying storm/tests/databases/postgres.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n  copying storm/tests/databases/sqlite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n  copying storm/tests/databases/proxy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n  copying storm/tests/databases/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n  copying storm/tests/databases/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/django\n  copying storm/tests/django/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/django\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n  copying storm/tests/store/block.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n  copying storm/tests/store/postgres.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n  copying storm/tests/store/sqlite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n  copying storm/tests/store/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n  copying storm/tests/store/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n  copying storm/tests/zope/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n  copying storm/tests/zope/adapters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n  copying storm/tests/zope/zstorm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n  copying storm/tests/zope/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n  copying storm/tests/schema/schema.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n  copying storm/tests/schema/sharding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n  copying storm/tests/schema/patch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n  copying storm/tests/schema/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n  running egg_info\n  writing storm.egg-info/PKG-INFO\n  writing dependency_links to storm.egg-info/dependency_links.txt\n  writing requirements to storm.egg-info/requires.txt\n  writing top-level names to storm.egg-info/top_level.txt\n  reading manifest file 'storm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'\n  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'\n  no previously-included directories found matching 'storm/docs/_build'\n  no previously-included directories found matching 'db'\n  writing manifest file 'storm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'\n  copying storm/cextensions.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  copying storm/zope/configure.zcml -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/zope/meta.zcml -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n  copying storm/docs/Makefile -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/api.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/index.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/infoheritance.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/tutorial.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  copying storm/docs/zope.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n  running build_ext\n  building 'storm.cextensions' extension\n  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8\n  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c storm/cextensions.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/cextensions.o\n  storm/cextensions.c:23:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory\n     23 | #include <Python.h>\n        |          ^~~~~~~~~~\n  compilation terminated.\n  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1\n  ----------------------------------------\n  ERROR: Failed building wheel for storm\n    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:\n     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3pa_d1bw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/storm\n         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/\n    Complete output (124 lines):\n    running install\n    running build\n    running build_py\n    creating build\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/uri.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/database.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/properties.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/locals.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/references.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/xid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/store.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/sqlobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/event.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/variables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/expr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/tracer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n    copying storm/twisted/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n    copying storm/twisted/transact.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n    copying storm/twisted/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/twisted\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n    copying storm/databases/postgres.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n    copying storm/databases/sqlite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n    copying storm/databases/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/databases\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/uri.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/database.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/properties.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/helper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/sqlobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/event.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/variables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/expr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/tracer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/mocker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    copying storm/tests/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/metaconfigure.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/metadirectives.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/adapters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/zstorm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/schema.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/conf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n    copying storm/schema/schema.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n    copying storm/schema/sharding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n    copying storm/schema/patch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n    copying storm/schema/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/schema\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/twisted\n    copying storm/tests/twisted/transact.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/twisted\n    copying storm/tests/twisted/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/twisted\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n    copying storm/tests/databases/postgres.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n    copying storm/tests/databases/sqlite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n    copying storm/tests/databases/proxy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n    copying storm/tests/databases/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n    copying storm/tests/databases/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/databases\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/django\n    copying storm/tests/django/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/django\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n    copying storm/tests/store/block.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n    copying storm/tests/store/postgres.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n    copying storm/tests/store/sqlite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n    copying storm/tests/store/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n    copying storm/tests/store/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/store\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n    copying storm/tests/zope/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n    copying storm/tests/zope/adapters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n    copying storm/tests/zope/zstorm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n    copying storm/tests/zope/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/zope\n    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n    copying storm/tests/schema/schema.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n    copying storm/tests/schema/sharding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n    copying storm/tests/schema/patch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n    copying storm/tests/schema/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/tests/schema\n    running egg_info\n    writing storm.egg-info/PKG-INFO\n    writing dependency_links to storm.egg-info/dependency_links.txt\n    writing requirements to storm.egg-info/requires.txt\n    writing top-level names to storm.egg-info/top_level.txt\n    reading manifest file 'storm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'\n    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'\n    no previously-included directories found matching 'storm/docs/_build'\n    no previously-included directories found matching 'db'\n    writing manifest file 'storm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'\n    copying storm/cextensions.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    copying storm/zope/configure.zcml -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/zope/meta.zcml -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/zope\n    copying storm/docs/Makefile -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/api.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/index.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/infoheritance.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/tutorial.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    copying storm/docs/zope.rst -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/docs\n    running build_ext\n    building 'storm.cextensions' extension\n    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8\n    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm\n    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c storm/cextensions.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/storm/cextensions.o\n    storm/cextensions.c:23:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory\n       23 | #include <Python.h>\n          |          ^~~~~~~~~~\n    compilation terminated.\n    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1\n    ----------------------------------------\nERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nuqyzvzg/storm/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3pa_d1bw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/storm Check the logs for full command output.\n"}[0m

Comment: The `storm` module needs to be installed on the remote host on which the module is running, not on your local host where you're running the playbook. You may need an ansible task to install `storm` on your target hosts before the `ssh_config task.

Comment: Okay could you convert your comment to an answer that includes `ansible.builtin.pip` (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) so that I can upvote and accept?

Comment: `pip install stormssh`

Comment: @phd you may be right because if I only install `storm` then I get a different error.

Comment: Confirmed, I needed `stormss`, not `storm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stormssh` module needs to be installed on the remote host on which the module is running, not on your local host where you're running the playbook. You may need an ansible task to install `stormssh` on your target hosts before the `ssh_config` task.

Possibly something like:

```
- name: Install stormssh module
  pip:
    name: stormssh

- name: Add Bitbucket in the SSH configuration
  community.general.ssh_config:
    user: "{{ jenkins_user }}"
    host: bitbucket
    remote_user: git
    hostname: "{{ bitbucket_hostname }}"
    port: '7999'
    identity_file: "/home/{{ jenkins_user }}/.ssh/{{ ssh_private_key }}"
    state: present
```